# Are there anyway to refactor the location functions into new myLocationHelper class

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions, location

**
hello, everybody
I have this code and i want to refactor it into class named LocationHelper Class but i didn't how to do it because permission function and when i do it with Futures it give me errors in setState

but the problem how to move and get the result of permission function to the new class
**

```
class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  String? _currentAddress;
  Position? _currentPosition;

  Future<bool> _handleLocationPermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location services are disabled. Please enable the services')));
      return false;
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Location permissions are denied')));
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.')));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) return;
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() => _currentPosition = position);
      _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placemarks) {
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.subAdministrativeArea}, ${place.postalCode}';
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Location Page")),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('LAT: ${_currentPosition?.latitude ?? ""}'),
              Text('LNG: ${_currentPosition?.longitude ?? ""}'),
              Text('ADDRESS: ${_currentAddress ?? ""}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 32),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _getCurrentPosition,
                child: const Text("Get Current Location"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so i want to refactore the location function into new class